# Search Telerik MVC 2.0 Grid using a partial view

Tags: telerik-mvc

I want to search Telerik MVC 2.0 GridView  I have a "*Index*" View on which a Grid is rendered at first then clicking on a "*Show History*" `Ajax.ActionLink` opens a PartialView "*SearchGrid*" .

In this View there are 2 Telerik MVC DatePickers and a submit button.. On clicking of Submit button sends DatePicker Values back to UploadFiles Controller's 
`SearchByDates( DateTime? frmDate,DateTime? toDate)` Action.

Here in this action I am fetching records for Updates in between UpdateDates **i.e.** *frmDate & toDate* Values, from DB using WorkerService class and Services class.

Everything works fine till this point, But My problem is with Ajax , after UploadFilesViewModel's GetUploadDescriptor is bound with UploadFilesGrid , again a call is made to SearchByDates action , url.Action which is on JS code is again called and not parameters are passed. When at first the call to this action is made FormCollection doesn't contain anything but when next time a new call is made FormCollection values contain frmDate,toDate.

Finally an empty Grid is displayed. I don't know what I am doing wrong ..

Source Code :-

```
     My GridView:-
<div id="result">
   <div>
      <%: Ajax.ActionLink ( "Show History", "SearchGrid", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get",  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "renderForm", OnSuccess = "updateTarget" }, new { @class = "t-button" } )%>
    </div>
  <div id="di">
   <% Html.Telerik().Grid<UploadedFilesDescriptor>()
         .Name("UploadedFilesGrid")
       .DataKeys(datakeys => datakeys.Add(m => m.Id))
      .ClientEvents ( events => events.OnDataBound ( "rebindFileListGrid" ) )

        columns.Bound(c => c.UploadedDate)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center;" })
                .Width(100);                   
           })
            .DataBinding(databinding => databinding
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .Select("GetUploadedFilesList",     "UploadFiles"))
                                  .EnableCustomBinding ( true )                
                      .Render();
                     %>
                   </div>
             </div>


 : My SearchGrid PartialView :-

 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm( "SearchByDates","UploadFiles",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId ="divUploadGrid",LoadingElementId = "LoadingImage"},new {@id= "itemForm"}))
{ %>
      //Two Telerik MVC DatePickers named "frmDate" and " toDate"
  <input type="submit" id="ProfileSearchSubmit" name="ProfileSearchSubmit" onclick="aClick();" value="Search" /> 

  <div id="divUploadFileGrid">
   --I am again Rendering the Serached Grid with same model, columns 
  </div> 


    //my Javascript Jquery Ajax Function 
        function aClick() {
         debugger;
          var to = $('#toDate').val().toString();
         var frm = $('#frmDate').val().toString();
         var params = "frmDate=" + frm + "&toDate=" + to;
        if (params != null) {
           $.ajax({
              url: '<%= Url.Action("SearchByDates","UploadFiles") %>'+"?"+params,
              cache: false,               
             success: function (html) {
             $("#divUploadGrid").show();
               },                
             complete: function () {
              $("#LoadingImage").css("display", "none");
             $("#divUploadGrid").css("display", "block");
              $("#result").hide();
                }
              });
           }
            };

    :- Controller Action :-
      public ActionResult SearchByDates( DateTime? frmDate, DateTime?  toDate,FormCollection colletion)
           {
           try
             {
                DateTime? fromDate = frmDate.Value;
                DateTime? toDates = toDate.Value;
               UploadedFilesViewModel model = new UploadedFilesViewModel ( );
               model.GetUploadFileDescriptor = _workerService.GetUploadGridByDates(fromDate, toDates );
               return PartialView ( "SearchGrid", model );                   
            }
          catch (Exception ex)
           {
             throw ex;
           }
         return null;
         }

     :- GridAction to bind records in GridView
              public ActionResult GetUploadedFilesList ( DateTime? frmDate, DateTime? toDate )
            {        
                try
                {
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()&& frmDate==null&&toDate==null)
                    {
                    return View ( new GridModel ( _workerService.GetUploadedFilesList ( ) ) );
                    }
                else
                    {
                    return View ( new GridModel ( _workerService.GetUploadGridByDates ( frmDate, toDate ) ) ); 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    bool reThrow = ExceptionPolicyWrapper.HandleException(ex, ExceptionPolicies.MVCPolicy);
                    if (reThrow)
                        throw;
                }
                return null;
                }
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to give an answer to this without any source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 2 simultaneous requests:

- by Ajax.BeginForm;
- by defined onclick="aClick();" attribute in your submit button ( 'aClick' function triggers another ajax request inside its body).

I'd suggest you to remove onclick attribute from your submit button.
If you need to run javascript routing before ajax form submittion you can define AjaxOptions.OnBegin option:

new AjaxOptions{
...,
OnBegin="onBegin"
}

```
function onBegin(e){
  ...
}
```

Inside this function you can do:

- change the request' body value;
- cancel submittion by returning false value.

In case your DatePicker controlls are located inside 
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm( "SearchByDates","UploadFiles".. construct these are all changes required.
Otherwise, you need to define onBegin function this way:

```
function onBegin(e){

var to = $('#toDate').val();
var frm = $('#frmDate').val();

var req = e.get_request();
var req_body = req.get_body();
req_body += "&frmDate=" + frm + "&toDate=" + to;

req.set_body(req_body);

return true;
}
```

This makes sure your DatePickers values are submitted as well.

Comment: But how to rebind Grid after complete search is done ...  I   get no  column values in my grid ..I don't know what is happening with my GridSearch

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define onclick event handler on your submit button.
Ajax.BeginForm construct issues ajax request on its own passing your DatePickers' values.

Comment: I have to construct a onclick event handler on submit button as I have to pass datepicker values back to Controller .. Without this I am not able to pass them

Comment: It is not clear from the source code where those DatePicker controls are located. In case they are inside the Ajax form, they will be send with the Post request automatically. Otherwise, you can use jQuery ajax functionality and disable Ajax.BeginForm's one by returning false from 'aClick' handler (but don't forget to use html you get in success: handler to update divUploadGrid.

Comment: They are inside Ajax form but I don't know how those datepicker values are not accessible in my controller , even  formCollection values are coming out as NULL

Comment: Ok Update :- Those values are accessible inside controller but after Grid is searched and model is returned back to Grid but I don't know somehow again a new call to Controller's SearchedGrid method is made where DatePickerPicker values are coming as null and so no searching of grid is made ..so a normal Model is returned back to Grid